# Put tables under subsections

Tags: tables, sectioning

So, for an assignment in one of my classes, we are supposed to provide some data in the form of tables. So, what I want to do is put my tables under a certain number of subsections, but when I do this:

```
\section*{Test Results}
Below are the results for each tester.
\subsection*{Tester 1}
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabular}{|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|}
\hline
Safari&Print&Set Homepage&Zoom\\
\hline
Time(Seconds)&40&32&20\\
\hline
Errors&Couldn't find the print button&Clicked the wrong menu button&N/A\\
\hline
Likeability(1 to 10)&6&7&8\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\vspace{-2em}
\begin{tabular}{|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|}
\hline
Opera&Print&Set Homepage&Zoom\\
\hline
Time(Seconds)&37&226 (3 mins. 46 secs.)&17\\
\hline
Errors&Couldn't find the print button/No Confirmation of print&Opened Chrome to learn how to set an Opera Page/Difficult to find preferences&Mis-clicked on Zoom button.\\
\hline
Likeability(1 to 10)&6&0&7\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\subsection*{Tester 2}
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|}
\hline
Safari&Print&Set Homepage&Zoom\\
\hline
Time(Seconds)&8&22&32\\
\hline
Errors&N/A&Found it difficult to change home page in settings.&Had a hard time finding zoom button.\\
\hline
Likeability(1 to 10)&8&7&5\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|}
\hline
Opera&Print&Set Homepage&Zoom\\
\hline
Time(Seconds)&5&338 (5 mins. 38 secs.)&8\\
\hline
Errors&N/A&Couldn't find out how to make a home page/Googled the results, looked in various places to learn how to set the web page.&N/A\\
\hline
Likeability(1 to 10)&6&0&7\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

My document produces the subsections *before* my tables. Is there anyway I can get my data under their respective subsections?

Comment: Have you tried loading the `placeins` package and inserting `\FloatBarrier` instructions before the `\subsection` instructions?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  You could add a `\clearpage` _before_ the `\subsection`.  Also, while code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: You *don't* have to use a `table` in order to use a `tabular`. Just use `{\centering \begin{tabular}... \end{tabular}\par}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A combination of (a) using `[h!]` as the location specifier and (b) inserting `\clearpage` immediately before the second `\subsection*` instruction should do the job. Incidentally, since you have *four* `tabular` environments, you should provide *four* (not three) `table` environments. Better still, since the tables aren't supposed to float anyway, don't use *any* `table` environments.